# How can I filter nodes by property values and labels in using Cypher query?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I'm trying to use Cypher to perform a graph search that includes node filtering based on property values and label constraints. I want to find all nodes with a name property that starts with "**Mc**" and is labeled as `Manufacturer`.

I've tried the following code:

```
MATCH (n:Manufacturer)
WHERE n.name "Mc*"
RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `STARTS WITH` clause with `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'Mc'
```

Everthing else remains the same in your query.